# How to disable auto deletion of files in my Chromebook's Downloads folder?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, chromebook

How can I stop the files in my Downloads folder from being automatically deleted when I begin to run low on space?

Ref: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1061547